# Compile node_modules @types folder in typescript

Tags: typescript

i am building a module for npm which uses **@types/crypto-js** as a dependency. I am building this module in typescript the problem is that when i **Compile the code into dist folder** it contains only index.js files and **does not compile crypto-js module** which when i run a test it says module crypto-js not found. any answers?
this is my *tsconfig.json*

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2017", "es7", "es6", "dom"],
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": [
    "node_modules/@types/crypto-js"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@types/*` packages provide type declarations only. They always compile down to nothing in plain JavaScript. You need to also depend on the `crypto-js` package itself, which provides the actual functionality.

I wasn't sure from your description if you're building a package for distribution on NPM or not. If you are, you don't need to bundle `crypto-js` into your package at all (and probably shouldn't); merely listing the dependency is enough. Anyone who installs your package will then also get `crypto-js` automatically.